# Playwright downloads weird file

Tags: node.js, playwright

I'm using playwright to download some file but whatever i try to download playwright is downloading this:

[image: Download]

Is the third time i get this error and i dont know what it is...

[image: browser]

This is the code and what i get using
`npx playwright codegen https://signup.euw.leagueoflegends.com/es/signup/redownload`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
const [ download ] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForEvent('download'),
    page.click('text=Descargar para Windows')
]);

await download.saveAs('filename.abc');
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works!! I suppose that pw was downloading a request and with last line u wait for it.

Comment: Happy it worked. Would you then pls accept & upvote the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using csharp with playwright:

```
  var downloadTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<IDownload>();
            Page.Download += (sender, download) => downloadTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(download);

            await Page.ClickAsync("buttonlocator");

            var download = await downloadTaskCompletionSource.Task;

            // Wait for the download process to complete
            Console.WriteLine(await download.PathAsync());

            // Save downloaded file somewhere
            await download.SaveAsAsync("pathtosavefilewithextension");
```