# Download files in Playwright with proper file name

Tags: javascript, playwright, webautomation

here I have solution for download files

```
  const [download] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForResponse(res => res.status() >= 200, {timeout:100000}),
    page.click("[name='action_selectPassword']", {timeout:100000})
    ])
```

And I want to have normal name of download file.

`download.suggestedFilename()`
but with this I have error suggestedFilename is not a function.

I run browser with launchPersistentContext option with downloadPath.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Playwright downloads weird file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70876812/playwright-downloads-weird-file)

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for a download rather than a response:

```
const [download] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForEvent('download', {timeout:100000}),
    page.click("[name='action_selectPassword']", {timeout:100000})
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, yes now it works but still I straggle with download proper name

```
launchPersistantContentext(downloadsPath: 'C:\\download')

const [download] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForEvent('download', {timeout:100000}),
    page.click("[name='action_selectPassword']", {timeout:100000})
    ]);

const fileName = await download.suggestedFilename();
await download.saveAs(fileName);
```

But it looks like PW use downloadsPath from the top and don't use saveAs